# Persisting Python error: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have 2 scripts for GCS (Google Cloud Storage) to upload and download files. I installed google.cloud using `pip install google`. My scripts were working, but now I see error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'`

I read many questions here for same issue, but didn't find solution.

What I tried:

- upgrading pip
- `pip uninstall google` and `pip3 install google`
- re-installing VS Code
- I tried following:

  `pip install virtualenv virtualenv venv source venv/bin/activate pip install google-cloud-storage`

Here `source venv/bin/activate` didn't run in Terminal

Can you please help me?

When I do `pip list` I see:

```
    Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
beautifulsoup4           4.10.0   
cachetools               4.2.4    
certifi                  2021.10.8
charset-normalizer       2.0.9
distlib                  0.3.4
filelock                 3.4.2
google                   3.0.0
google-api-core          2.3.2
google-api-python-client 2.34.0
google-auth              2.3.3
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
google-cloud             0.34.0
google-cloud-core        2.2.1
google-cloud-storage     1.43.0
google-crc32c            1.3.0
google-resumable-media   2.1.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.54.0
httplib2                 0.20.2
idna                     3.3
pip                      21.3.1
platformdirs             2.4.1
protobuf                 3.19.1
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pyparsing                3.0.6
requests                 2.26.0
rsa                      4.8
six                      1.16.0
soupsieve                2.3.1
uritemplate              4.1.1
urllib3                  1.26.7
virtualenv               20.13.0
```

People asked my code. Here it is. (Although it's not needed to solve question)
Code that I run:

Note:
(it uploads to GCS. files have names like "Customer- ...", "Account- ...". The type of the file is uploaded to named accordingly Prefix in Bucket [bucket_name/Prefix_name] I called it file_type_name in a code)

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import glob
import json
import sys

def upload_files(config_file):
    # Reading 3 Parameters for upload from JSON file
    with open(config_file, "r") as file:
        contents = json.loads(file.read())

    # Setting up login credentials
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = contents['login_credentials']
    # The ID of GCS bucket
    bucket_name = contents['bucket_name']
    # Setting path to files
    LOCAL_PATH = contents['folder_from']

    for source_file_name in glob.glob(LOCAL_PATH + '/**'):

    # For multiple files upload
    # Setting destination folder according to file name 
        if os.path.isfile(source_file_name):
            partitioned_file_name = os.path.split(source_file_name)[-1].partition("-")
            file_type_name = partitioned_file_name[0]

            # Setting folder where files will be uploaded
            destination_blob_name = file_type_name + "/" + os.path.split(source_file_name)[-1]

            # Setting up required variables for GCS 
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
            blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

            # Running upload and printing confirmation message
            blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
            print("File from {} uploaded to {} in bucket {}.".format(
                source_file_name, destination_blob_name, bucket_name
            ))


upload_files(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: How do you call it (and import it) in your script? Sounds to me more like a typo in the import statement.  Try changing to "from google.cloud import storage" and referring to storage for example.

Comment: Please, share the code your are trying to run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added code! It's below my question

Answer (score 0):

my friend helped me to solve it. I'm using Visual Studio Code and I had to change Python interpreter. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "interpreter". From the list I chosen `Python 3.9.9 64-bit (windows store)`. Hopefully it will be helpful for someone